# ¿Como puedo imprimir los valores de un datagrid en un archivo de texto en VB 6.0? ya puedo desde una caja de texto el problema es

Tags: vba, vb6

Cuando intento tomar directo el valor de la caja de texto, si me lo pasa al txt pero solamente ese registro, intente tomando desde el adodc pero no funciona, ¿podria tomar todo el datagrid y recorrerlo con un for o alguna otra manera? Por que lo que tengo en el datagrid tambien lo muestra en las cajas de texto y para recorrerlo, utilizo el adodc.

`Nombre = Application.Inputbox Open App.Path & "" & Nombre & ".txt" For Append As #1`

`Print #1, Trim(txtNoEmpleado2.Text), Trim(txtNombre.Text)`

`Close #1`

`MsgBox "Se guardaron los datos correctamente", vbInformation, "DATOS GUARDADOS"`

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente es recorrer el DataGid como filas y luego cada fila como celdas:

```
Dim celda As Variant
For Fila = 0 To DataGrid.ApproxCount - 1
   ' comienza la linea
   For Columna = 0 To DataGrid.Columns.Count - 1
     celda = DataGrid.Columns(Columna).CellValue(DataGrid.GetBookmark(Fila))
     ' escribir celda     
   Next
   ' finalizar la linea
Next
```

Este es un ejemplo que te puede servir, exporta en HTML pero puedes simplificarlo revisa la function `Exportar_DataGrid_Html()`

https://www.recursosvisualbasic.com.ar/htm/trucos-codigofuente-visual-basic/270-exportar-datagrid-a-html.htm